# jquery 1.9.1 .trigger() not passing arguments to click-handler

Tags: jquery, triggers, parameter-passing

With jQuery 1.9.1 arguments are not passed from a trigger to the click handler, as where with jquery 1.7.2 they are nicely passed.

An example to demonstrate:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script-->
</head>
<body>
    <input id="test" type="checkbox">
    <button id='trigger'>trigger</button>

</body>
    <script>
        $('#test').bind('click',
            function (e, data){
                if (typeof data == 'undefined') {
                    alert('no data passed');
                    return;
                }
                alert('first passed=' + data.passed1 + ' second passed='+data.passed2);
            });

        $('#trigger').click(
            function (e){
                $('#test').trigger('click',{passed1:'first',passed2:'second'});

        });
    </script>
</html>
```

When I use jquery-1.7.2.js it still works fine.

What am I missing? Please help me.

Comment: Why are you closing `body` before the `script`??

Comment: None of the syntaxes seem to work after testing, seems like a bug.

Comment: Looks like a strange bug. http://jsfiddle.net/xHVDx/1/

Comment: Your original syntax seems to work with non-checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/9mD6a/ it also works in checkboxes with events other than click http://jsfiddle.net/9mD6a/1/ seems like a corner-case bug.

Comment: This still works with 1.8.3, it seems support ends there however.

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong in your opinion with current answer ?

Answer (score 7):

It's a known issue: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13353

Workaround is to use .triggerHandler() instead e.g.:

```
$('#trigger').click(function (e) {
    var $test = $('#test');       
    $test
        .prop('checked', !$test.prop('checked'))
        .triggerHandler('click',{passed1:'first',passed2:'second'});        
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/xHVDx/2

Triggering clicks is evil in any case (if the intention is just to run the callback)

Comment: Echoing @antishok: Don't trigger clicks this way. Separate the handler code out into its own function and call it directly instead.